# eclipse import gradle project download take forever

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, libgdx

i tried to generate project with libgdx and then import it to eclipse but it take forever more than 5 hours on downloading dependencies , however it works fine from the command line but not eclipse or even netbeans (same problem)

[image]

so what is the problem ?

is there any way to work around that and install the dependencies offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand your question, you can generate a project with libgdx setup in advance button, click on eclipse, offline mode, Gradle, download the dependencies on your computer. to import into eclipse the setup, where advanced eclipse click shows how to do it.

**setup libGDX**

[image]

**advanced click**

[image]

**click eclipse and offline mode**

then click generate, when finished, you just have to import it into eclipse. I hope you help.